# Is there any mobile ads network that works within an Appgyver Steroids app?

Tags: mobile, admob, adsense, ads, steroids

As far as I know, it's still impossibile to implement AdMob in Steroids applications. I also tried InMoby and many more networks but none of them worked, because Steroids is a cross platform framework.

Networks like AdSense can't obviously be used because they need to be run inside a specific web domain.

Answer (score 0):

We at AppGyver have used AdMob successfully before using [this plugin](https://github.com/AppGyver/phonegap-admob-plugin). However, the plugin has not been updated in several months so it's not guaranteed to work out-of-the-box, but it is a good starting point for integrating AdMob to your app.